# How to fetch file properties from Content document object using API

Tags: contentdocument, contentdocumentlink

I am trying to get all the files attached to a case. I have found a way to download the files attached to case using

`sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/${contentDocumentIdLink}?operationContext=S1`

but I was unable to get the file properties such as name,size,type of the file.

- Is there any API which could help me pull all this details. I have been trying to use

`services/data/v41.0/sobjects/ContentDocument/ContentDocumentId`

but for some reason it is returning Invalid session Id.

```
[
    {
        "message": "Session expired or invalid",
        "errorCode": "INVALID_SESSION_ID"
    }
]
```

NOTE : I have admin credentials for that org.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the all details of your API call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query you need to use to get files linked to a case would be

```
SELECT Id, ContentDocument.Title, ...
   FROM ContentDocumentLink
   WHERE LinkedEntityId = 'theCaseId'
```

Reference [ContentDocumentLink in Object Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm?q=contentdocumentlink)

> Represents the link between a Salesforce CRM Content document, Salesforce file, or ContentNote and where it's shared. A file can be shared with other users, groups, records, and Salesforce CRM Content libraries. This object is available in versions 21.0 and later for Salesforce CRM Content documents and Salesforce Files.

Since you are doing this as REST, you can convert the SOQL into a REST query [using the REST API doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_query.htm?q=query)

Comment: I want an API not a query.

Comment: @Jakkarohith - I assumed you could convert a SOQL query to the corresponding API - see [REST API guide on querying](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_query.htm?q=query)

Comment: Thank you this article was helpful. If possible can you edit you answer and place this link over there it would be helpful for others who has the same issue